# Creating an Opportunity on Lead Conversion without creating an Account or Contact

Tags: apex, trigger, opportunity, lead-conversion

Please how to convert lead to Opportunity without creating account and contacts

```
trigger LeadConvert on Lead (after update) {

    if(trigger.new.size() > 1) 
            return;

    if (trigger.old[0].isConverted == false && trigger.new[0].isConverted == true) {

        // if a new contact was created
        if (Trigger.new[0].ConvertedContactId != null) {
            ContactCookie__c contCk = new ContactCookie__c();
            contCk.Contact__c = trigger.new[0].ConvertedContactId;
            contCk.Name = trigger.new[0].Name;
        }
        // if a new account was created
        if (Trigger.new[0].ConvertedAccountId != null) {
            //Similarly customize the converted account
        }
        // if a new opportunity was created
        if (Trigger.new[0].ConvertedOpportunityId != null) {
            //Similarly customize the converted Opportunity
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As a Workaround you can create a dummy account and associate this account to converted lead.
Or you can delete the account and contact which are created because of lead conversion (I am not sure what is your business requirement)

Comment: If you aren't creating a Contact then you aren't really converting the Lead. Perhaps you want to use another mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

You can go with following approach (see comments in code):-

```
  if (trigger.old[0].isConverted == false && trigger.new[0].isConverted == true) {

    // if a new contact was created
    if (Trigger.new[0].ConvertedContactId != null) {
        ContactCookie__c contCk = new ContactCookie__c();
        contCk.Contact__c = trigger.new[0].ConvertedContactId;
        contCk.Name = trigger.new[0].Name;
    }
    // if a new account was created
    if (Trigger.new[0].ConvertedAccountId != null) {
        // IGNORE THIS ***** No Operation needed
    }
    // if a new opportunity was created
    if (Trigger.new[0].ConvertedOpportunityId != null) {
         /*
                1. Fetch the Opportunity record by ConvertedOpportunityId
                2. Empty the Account Id field of Opportunity Record
                3. Update the opportunity
                4. Delete that Account

         */
    }
}
```